# Display single data member of related data using Entity Framework in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I have two related entities in Entity Framework, `Stock` and then `Suppliers` in which one stock entity can have one supplier and a supplier can have many stocks items.

I have a data grid in which i want to display all the data about Stock such as the Id, Name, Price etc and include the `SuppliersId` for it.

In the screenshot below I want it to display the `SuppliersId` where it says Supplier but i cannot get it so it doesn't include just the string of the entire object.

[Screenshot of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjcSP.png)

The stock class

```
class Stock
{
    public Stock()
    {
        this.SalesInvolvedIn = new HashSet<Sales>();
    }

    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public string StockName { get; set; }
    public int StockPrice { get; set; }
    public string StockType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sales> SalesInvolvedIn { get; set; }

    public Suppliers Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

Fetching the data

```
public List<Stock> GetStock()
{                        
    return StockManagementDatabaseContext.Stocks.Include("Suppliers").ToList();
}
```

Updating the data grid

```
private void UpdateStockList()
{
    List<Stock> stocklist = repository.GetStock();

    this.StockDataGrid.ItemsSource = stocklist;
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: Showing the Supplier Class

```
class Suppliers
{
    public int SuppliersId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Stock> StockSold { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where’s the xaml of your DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you just want to show the supplier Id? Two approaches come to mind: `ViewModel` or not using autogenerated columns in the datagrid in XAML.

You could create a `ViewModel` like this:

```
public class StockViewModel
{
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public string StockName { get; set; }
    public int StockPrice { get; set; }
    //etc....
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
}
```

Fetch the data to it:

```
public List<StockViewModel> GetStock()
{                        
    return StockManagementDatabaseContext.Stocks.Include("Suppliers")
    .Select(a => new StockViewModel
    {
         StockId = a.StockId,
         StockName = a.StockName,
         StockPrice = a.StockPrice,
         //and any other you may wish to include
         SupplierId = a.Suppliers.SuppliersId
    }).ToList();
}
```

Load to your grid

```
private void UpdateStockList()
{
   this.StockDataGrid.ItemsSource = repository.GetStock();
}
```

Alternatively you can choose what you want your grid to bind in XAML by setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to **False**

```
    <DataGrid Name="StockDataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"             
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding StockId }"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding StockName }"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding StockPrice}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier ID" Binding="{Binding Suppliers.SupplierId}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and its definitely what im after, however when trying to implement your code it has come up with 2 errors. It may be missing something. The errors are as follows; "CS1061 'Suppliers' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Suppliers' could be found" and "CS1061 'StockViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'StockViewModel' could be found

Comment: I'm not sure where to start hunting for those errors but I did make a few changes to my answer: I've changed the `ViewModel` to public and and `GetStock()` to return `List<StockViewModel>` and then loading to grid accordingly.

Comment: Ah, perhaps `using System.Data.Entity;`?

Comment: Thanks for your extended help! This has fixed the `ToList` error but the `Select` one persists, the error is on the line `SupplierId = a.Suppliers.Select(b => b.SupplierId).FirstOrDefault()` in the GetStock method. And using system.data.entity unfortunately doesnt fix it. Could it be something to do with my `Suppliers` class?

Comment: Try changing it to `a.Suppliers.SuppliersId`. Providing your `Suppliers` class will be necessary if this still doesn't work.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work either, added the `Supplier` class code as an edit to the original question. Also `using System.Data.Entity` is grayed out/ not used in the class where `GetStock` is located, but surely it needs to be?

Comment: `System.Data.Entity` is not being used without the `SupplierId = a.Suppliers.Select(b => b.SupplierId).FirstOrDefault()`. andrensairr is right, I've changed the answer as well accordingly. I had a little bit different testing environment when I tried my original answer but I've tested the edited solution something more similar to yours. Still not certain why yours isn't working though.

Comment: Ahh... i didn't fully understand andrensairr's suggestion and changed it to `a.Suppliers.SuppliersId.Select(b => b.SupplierId).FirstOrDefault()` rather than just `SupplierId = a.Suppliers.SuppliersId
           }).ToList();` just in the vain hope of it working. However your edit has explained it to me, and now it fully works it! Thanks alot to the both of you! Finally fixed the problem ive been stuck with for a while.